# invalid time series parameters specified

Tags: r, forecast

I'm trying to use arima with R to make a forecast querying data from SQL Server. How do you fix this? The error is:

Error in attr(x, "tsp") <- c(1, NROW(x), 1) :

invalid time series parameters specified

The original example used class(AirPassengers) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5T3ZEMZZKs
Or does anyone have an example of R arima model using data from a sql database?

```
library(forecast)

conn = odbcConnect("Test")
wine <- sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT [Month]
      ,[Price]
  FROM [dbo].[wine]")

# time series dataset:
class(wine)

start(dput(wine))
end(wine)
frequency(wine) # 12 months
sum(is.na(data)) # check for missing values; no missing values
```

---

I changed the dataset format. How do you get rid of the row id that's generated? It's not in the database table. That may be the problem?
[image]

Sample data:

```r
wine <- structure(list("column 0" = c("Month", "Price", "Year"), "column 1" = c("1", "7.495", "2022"), "column 2" = c("2", "8.0393", "2022"), "column 3" = c("3", "7.6858", "2022"), "column 4" = c("4", "6.9845", "2022"), "column 5" = c("5", "6.7772", "2022"), "column 6" = c("6", "8.0757", "2022"), "column 7" = c("7", "6.5188", "2022"), "column 8" = c("8", "8.4937", "2022"), "column 9" = c("9", "7.388", "2022"), "column 10" = c("10", "6.7127", "2022"), "column 11" = c("11", "7.3094", "2022"), "column 12" = c("12",  "6.2518", "2022"), "column 13" = c("1", "7.7443", "2023"), "column 14" = c("2", "6.8398", "2023"), "column 15" = c("3", "6.2435", "2023"), "column 16" = c("4", "6.3459", "2023"), "column 17" = c("5", "7.5883", "2023"), "column 18" = c("6", "7.1934", "2023"), "column 19" = c("7", "6.2049", "2023"), "column 20" = c("8", "6.6367", "2023"), "column 21" = c("9", "6.2941", "2023"), "column 22" = c("10", "7.292", "2023"), "column 23" = c("11", "7.1211", "2023"), "column 24" = c("12", "6.2587", "2023")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L), columninfo = structure(list(name = c("Column 0", "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4", "Column 5", "Column 6", "Column 7", "Column 8", "Column 9", "Column 10", "Column 11", "Column 12", "Column 13", "Column 14", "Column 15", "Column 16", "Column 17", "Column 18", "Column 19", "Column 20", "Column 21", "Column 22", "Column 23", "Column 24"), type = c("12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12",  "12", "12")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L)))
```

Comment: Your question is about forecasting on data, I don't see how SQL Server is relevant. Granted, you get data from it, but if the data is not structured correctly from SQL Server, then that is a different question. If you get the data okay, and the columns are the correct classes, then please [edit] your question and remove the database-stuff and replace it with usable data by pasting the output from `dput(wine)` into a [code block]. (If it's a lot of data, then perhaps just `dput(head(wine, 20))` or such to get the point across.)

Comment: I updated the question so you can see the screenshot.

Comment: To be candid ShielaE2021, I'm not going to spend time transcribing data from a screenshot into something I can play with quickly to see if it's a quick fix. I suggested `dput` for a reason. On top of me being seemingly lazy (not the case here), there are several other reasons: R objects often have hidden attributes that we cannot see or cannot reproduce reliably based on a picture and/or with what is just "printed" to the R console. Without those attributes, it's a guessing game. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info, please.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added the script for the table and data. I initially tried to post the entire script but I got an error that there's too much code.

Comment: The SQL code is not what I was suggesting, for several reasons. Most won't be able to use it, so let me help you provide sample data ...

Comment: Okay ... now, the "1 2 3" you have boxed in red in your picture are "row names", even though they look like numbers. They are harmless, and in many people's opinion, they should be ignored completely (there are some functions and utilities that use them meaningfully). `mtcars` is an example where the row names are meaningful. In your case, if you run `rownames(wine)` you'll get `c("1", "2", "3")`, R defaults to counting along the rows and storing as strings ... meh, it's what it is.

Comment: Bottom line, the `1 2 3` row names are not hampering anything you want to do.

Comment: One of several problems you have (caused by your now-removed SQL code) is that all of your data are strings, not numbers. What is driving you to create "data" in that way? You can get to the "Price" of your data with `price <- as.numeric(unlist(wine[2,-1]))`.

Comment: FYI, having data horizontally setup like that is not really aligned with how most R functions want to work with it. You might find it easier to see and use when vertical with three columns: `Year`, `Month`, and `Price`, such as ...

Comment: `wine2 <- structure(list(Year = c(2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L), Month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), Price = c(7.495, 8.0393, 7.6858, 6.9845, 6.7772, 8.0757, 6.5188, 8.4937, 7.388, 6.7127, 7.3094, 6.2518, 7.7443, 6.8398, 6.2435, 6.3459, 7.5883, 7.1934, 6.2049, 6.6367, 6.2941, 7.292, 7.1211, 6.2587 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))`

Comment: With that, you can start playing with time-series using `ts(wine2$Price)`, though there are likely more things you want to do with it.

Comment: Thank you! I thought R wanted data formated horizontally based on the sample code I'm using to learn. So I pasted the data in a file and imported the csv file into the SQL DB. That's why they're strings. I updated the columns to float. Are you saying The  data needs to be like in your next to last post? I'm getting dynamic data mainly from a SQL DB, sometimes files for a dashboard.

Comment: To upload data into SQL does not require that it must be strings, that was your doing when you used `VARCHAR`; SQL Server (and I think all other DBMSes) support INT, FLOAT, and some other types, all with varying levels of precision. I tend to find data structured as in my `wine2` example to be easier to work with for several reasons. On top of that, `dplyr` and `ggplot2` -- great packages when learning data-science-y things and for learning to produce plots -- both do very well in this "taller" mode.

Comment: When uploading a file it automatically sets the data type to varchar. That's what happened. Your example looks  like it's hard coded. This is for a dashboard that will be refreshed periodically. What do you recommend?

Comment: So much to unpack there ... (1) "uploading a file automatically sets ... varchar", what tool are you using that does _that_? That is not a reasonable default action. (I don't think `RODBC` does that, perhaps it's just you misunderstanding one of the utility functions.) (2) It is hard-coded because I'm not going to use the SQL `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT .. UNION .. SELECT .. UNION .. SELECT` mechanism. If your database tables are being created outside of your control using a horizontal layout with everything as strings, well ... wow. That's just not good.

Comment: I used the import wizard to import the csv file. This isn't live. The SQL DB data would be managed via ETL. That's why I'm trying to use a SQL query because the data will be in a SQL DB.